# Create picker for date and time together in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uidatepicker

I am creating two pickers for date and time using `UIDatePickerModeDate` and `UIDatePickerModeTime`, but I want to create one picker for date and time together. I am new to iOS development.

For date selection I use this code:

```
datePick = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 290, 120, 0)];
datePick.datePickerMode =UIDatePickerModeDate
```

For time selection I use this:

```
timePick = [[UIDatePicker alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 200, 120, 0)];
timePick.datePickerMode =UIDatePickerModeTime;
```

Now my question is how can I create one picker for both and time?

Answer (score 4):

You can choose not to set `datePickerMode` for your `datePick`. The `UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime` is the default. It's the same as:

```
datePick.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Following Code hope your problem will be resolve

```
        UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
        [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
        [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDateField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        self.dateOfBirth.inputView = datePicker;
        self.dateOfBirth.text = [self formatDate:datePicker.date];
```

Set Date and Time Formate by adding this method

```
- (NSString )formatDate:(NSDate )date
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"];
    NSString *formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return formattedDate;
}
```

To get updated value from date use this

```
 -(void)updateDateField:(id)sender
    {
        UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.dateTextField.inputView;
        self.dateTextField.text = [self formatDate:picker.date];
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understood very well your question, but if you want with the same picker to pick both date and time use

```
_datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
```

Comment: No, that's just the time, no date is included.