# create a custom UIDatePicker that is suitable for making appointments in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I would like to create a UDatePicker to allow users to make an appointment. The UIDatePicker should show 7 days ahead of the current day, and after the appointment is made, a notification will pop up showing that it is confirmed.

The UI doesn't matter, something basic is fine. Is that possible? I've been searching online but I couldn't find anything that could help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create picker for date and time together in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550958/create-picker-for-date-and-time-together-in-iphone)

Comment: Maybe this link can give you a starting point: https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/display-date-date-picker-ios-tutorial-ios10

Comment: @Khushbu yeah but i dont know how to code it..

Comment: @Manmohan_singhnope it's not. what i intend to do is different

Comment: @Nooblhu okay i'll check it out. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UIPickerViewDelegate, 
UIPickerViewDataSource
{

var pickerView: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

var arrDate = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    arrDate.append(Date().getDateStringWithFormate("yyyy-MM-dd", timezone: TimeZone.current.abbreviation()!))

    for i in 1...7
    {
        let dateAdded = Date().addDays(i)
        arrDate.append(dateAdded.getDateStringWithFormate("yyyy-MM-dd", timezone: TimeZone.current.abbreviation()!))
        print(arrDate)
    }


    pickerView = UIPickerView()
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.dataSource = self


    let keyboardToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 44))
    keyboardToolbar.barStyle = .black
    keyboardToolbar.tintColor = UIColor.white

    let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSLocalizedString("Done", comment: ""), style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(clickToKeyboardToolbarDone(sender:)))

    //(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(clickToKeyboardToolbarDone(sender:)))


    let flex = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)

    let items = [flex, barButtonItem]
    keyboardToolbar.setItems(items, animated: true)

    textField.inputAccessoryView = keyboardToolbar
    textField.inputView = pickerView

}

@IBAction func clickToKeyboardToolbarDone(sender: UIBarButtonItem)
{
    if(textField.isFirstResponder)
    {
        let selectedIndex = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        let currentDate = arrDate[selectedIndex]

        print("currentDate",currentDate)
    }

    textField.resignFirstResponder()

}

//MARK: - UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource Methods

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return arrDate.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    return arrDate[row]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}



//MARK: - All Date Extension
extension Date
{
   func getDateStringWithFormate(_ formate: String, timezone: String) -> String
    {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = formate
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: timezone)

    return formatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

You can use customepicker view, make array of dates by today upto 7 days, try this code.

Comment: 1. Do not use `dateFormat`, use `dateStyle`. 2. If you insist on using `dateFormat`, at least use the correct format. `mm` is for minutes. 3. There is no such method as `getDateStringWithFormate`. 4. Why not use a plain old `UIDatePicker` with the initial date set to 7 days from now, just like being asked in the question?

Comment: How can we do initial date set to 7 days from now? @rmaddy

Comment: I tried your code but i have this error : Value of type 'Date' has no member 'addDays' could you tell me how to solve it? @AnjiMendpara

Comment: @rmaddy how can we set the initial date using the UIDatePicker?

Comment: @booak55 set the date picker's `date` property with whatever date you want.

Comment: @rmaddy but if i do it like that I can't set the current date to be 7 days ahead

Comment: @booak55 Why not? You can set the date to any date you want, just as I said.

Comment: @rmaddy you actually asked a similar question on another site. (I'm trying to set the maximum date to be 7 days ahead of the current date ( today's date).) how did you solve this?

Comment: @booak55  For "addDays" for this, you need to add addDay func.